# Why doesn't my code compare the first and last number?

Tags: arrays, lua

I have to compare up to 5 numbers in my script. That also works quite well. However, my first and last number are not compared. What's the problem in my code?

```lua
local loaded = game.Workspace.TrommelValue.Value
local randomkugel =  {}
    
for i = 0,loaded-1 do  
    randomkugel[i] = math.random(1,6) 
    for index = 0, i+1 do 
        if i ~= index then
            if randomkugel[i]==randomkugel[index] then
                randomkugel[i]=math.random(1,6)
                index = 0
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What do you mean by "are not compared"? What are you even trying to achieve with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what game.Workspace.trommelValue.value is, but let's assume its a positive number.

First iteration

```
-- assign a random integer from [1-6] to `randomkugel[0]`
randomkugel[0] = math.random(1,6)
```

Now you run the inner loop the first time. The first cycle is skipped as `i == index`.
The second cylcle is skipped because `randomkugel[i]` is the random number and `randomkugel[index]` is `nil`

Second iteration of the outer loop. i is 1, random[1] is assigned a random value from [1-6].

Inner loop:
first run `i` is `1`, `index` is `0` so the first if statement is entered.
`randomkugel[1]` may randomly equal `randomkugel[0]`. In that case you would assign a new random value to `randomkugel[1]` and set `index` to `0` which does not have any effect.
In case both values are not equal nothing happens.
second cycle of the inner loop, `i` is still `1`, `index` is `2`.
As there is no `randomkugel[2]` this cycle does nothing.

You will always skip the last cycle of the inner loop as you're comparing vs `nil` every time.
So your inner loop is effectively

```
for index = 0, i do
  if i ~= index then
    if randomkugel[i]==randomkugel[index] then
      randomkugel[i]=math.random(1,6)
    end
  end
end
```

I guess your greatest misconception here is that you can somehow reset the loop counting variable index inside the loop body.
Any change to index is only valid after that change within the current iteration.